# Add windows commands in python

Tags: python, shutdown

Can anyone tell me how to add the shutdown.exe to python and how . i also want to set and variables like shutdown.exe -f -s -t 60

Answer (score 8):

The [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) allows you to run external programs from inside python. In particular [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is a really convenient way to run programs where you don't care about anything other than the return code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "60"])
```

#### Update:

You can pass anything you want as part of the list so you could create a `shutdown()` function like this:

```
import subprocess

def shutdown(how_long):
    subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", how_long])
```

So if we wanted to get user input directly from the console, we could do this:

```
dt = raw_input("shutdown> ")
dt = int(dt) #make sure dt is actually a number
dt = str(dt) #back into a string 'cause that's what subprocess.call expects
shutdown(dt)
```

Comment: how can i add a user input instead of the number 60??

Comment: you just use a variable? ensure that it's a number casting it to int, or you'll have very unpleasant consequences.